# Cannot take ownership of a file by Administrator even using command line

Tags: windows

I have copied and paste a directory between 2 windows server 2008 through remote desktop transiting via my local pc.

After pasting I deleted it. Then I realized it wasn't deleted and I couldn't access it. In securoty properties it shows message

"cannot display owner"

I tried changing owner without success through GUI I even typed in cmd with administrator right (see http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=23960 )

```
takeown /F <folder-path> /A /R
```

but it keeps saying access denied.

Is this a Windows 2008 bug ? Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused the problem, unless some of the folders are encrypted as well as secured.  However you should be able to copy/move them by booting from an ubuntu livecd which doesn't really respect the windows permissions.

Comment: I was going to suggest PSexec to local system, but this works just as well.